# Ultimo Filho Da Cadeia de Elemento

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma tabela de registros e preciso atualizar o ultimo elemento dentro de um `<td>`, supondo que tenho o código abaixo, há alguma maneira de pega o ultimo elemento da cadeia, o elemento `span` com classe? Alguma forma mais direta do que `.children.children`?

```
<...>
    <td>
     <span>
       <span>
         <span class="QueroEsteElemento">
</fechaTudo>
```

Comment: Já viu minha resposta abaixo ?

Comment: @Someone vi sim, pelo que entendi, é exatamente o que quero, mas acabou que achei uma maneira menos complexa de pegar o elemento que preciso, utilizei o id de outro elemento e adicionei uma palavra chave, no meu caso ficou mais simples e com menos código. Mas era isso que eu havia vindo pesquisando e não encontrava, obrigado.

Comment: @Bruno, postei uma resposta com a solução usando jQuery.... acho que é mais simples... a não ser que você não queira usar jQuery... :D

Comment: @MarllonNasser, não tenho nada contra jQuery kkkkkkk, até uso bastante ele, mas no meu problema não poderia ser aplicado por conta da seleção do elemento, mas é interessante também. Mas me ficou uma dúvida, na sua resposta você usou o ".html()" que busca em todo local da página, poderia ser alterado para algum elemento especifico?

Comment: Por que a seleção do elemento é um problema? Você não tem uma definição do quê você procura? Não é sempre um `span` dentro de uma `td`?

Comment: @MarllonNasser, nossa, desculpa, ainda estava com uma ideia de usar a classe na seleção. Nesse caso não é um problema, é sempre isso mesmo.

Comment: Então... tá aí. na minha opinião é a uma solução mais "clean".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o jQuery pode te ajudar com o [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/)

```js
alert($("span:last").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>teste1
        <span>teste2
             <span>teste3</span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o seguinte código

```
var list = document.getElementById("list").lastChild.innerHTML;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list;
```

E no seu HTML

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>StackOverflow</li>
    <li>mauro</li>
</ul>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

O retorno será **mauro**

Comment: Esse método retornará o último elemento da "primeira camada" do elemento, mas o que preciso está na última, sendo assim, precisaria utilizar 2~3 vezes o .lastChild ;

Comment: Então refaça a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Por enquanto não existe maneira nativa direta de pegar o elemento dentro de containers *"nested"*. Por enquanto você pode ter um método consumível:

(já vou avisando que não vou implementar esse método dentro de `HTMLElement#` por dois motivos:

- nem todos os navegadores tem essa interface `HTMLElement`;
- pode ser problemático com bibliotecas

)

---

Exemplo para funcionar em vários navegadores. Observação: pode perceber que usei `#childNodes` ao invés de `#children`, alguns navegadores velhos não suportam `#children`.

```
var castCollection,
    findLastNestedContainer;

findLastNestedContainer = function(container) {
    var child;
    for (; child = castCollection(container.childNodes)[0];)
        container = child;
    return container;
};

castCollection = function(collection) {
    var revised = [];
    var i, len, node;

    i = 0;
    len = collection.length;

    for (; i < len; ++i) {
        node = collection[i];
        if ((typeof node.nodeValue) !== "string")
            revised.push(node);
    }

    return revised;
};
```

Agora, finalmente vai a explicação:

- `findLastNestedContainer` pega um container HTML e vai verificando continuamente o primeiro elemento filho que o container atual tiver, até que não surja mais nenhum elemento HTML dentro de sí, por fim retorna o último container verificado.

Exemplo de uso:

```
findLastNestedContainer(elementoHTML)
```

Essa função vai te permitir fazer a captura direta de um (primeiro) elemento dentro de containers *nested*, não apenas dentro de um elementozinho.

Se você quer pegar o último elemento dentro de (um ou vários) elementos HTML, basta modificar a condição dentro do loop `for` no bloco da função `findLastNestedContainer`, para pegar o último elemento da coleção de filhos do container atual:

```
// Eu sei que poderia ter sido usado Array#last,
// mas nem todos navegadores suportam o getter
for (; (child = castCollection(container.childNodes))[child.length - 1];)
    container = child;
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode buscar o elemento pela classe.

```js
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
[].forEach.call(containers, function (container, indice) {
  var teste = container.querySelector(".teste");
  teste.textContent = "Teste " + indice;
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="teste">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="teste">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="teste">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```